# How to automatically call a controller function in symfony 4

Tags: php-7.2, symfony-4.3

I am trying to automate a task. Which is sending emails automatically every week to some people.
I created a MailController, inside it implemented a function which sends the emails.
What i want to do now is to make my app call the function automatically every week or month.

What i tried is to implement a new command which would execute my function and then make a script to repeat that command.

```
<?php

namespace App\Command;

use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputArgument;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;


    class MailCommand extends Command {

        protected function configure () {
            $defaultName = 'app:mailAuto';

            $this->setDescription("Permet d'envoyer des mails automatiquement lorsque le parc n'est pas à jour");

            $this->setHelp("Je serai affiche si on lance la commande bin/console app:mailAuto -h");

        }

        public function execute (InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output) {
            // $controller = new MailController();
            // $controller->warningMailAction();
            $output->writeln('coucou !');
        }
    }
```

When executing the command i created i get this messages:

```
In FileLoader.php line 166:
  The autoloader expected class "App\Command\commandeMailAuto" to be defined
  in file "/var/www/html/ParcAuto/vendor/composer/../../src/Command/commandeM
  ailAuto.php". The file was found but the class was not in it, the class nam
  e or namespace probably has a typo in /var/www/html/ParcAuto/config/service
  s.yaml (which is loaded in resource "/var/www/html/ParcAuto/config/services
  .yaml").

In DebugClassLoader.php line 213:
  The autoloader expected class "App\Command\commandeMailAuto" to be defined
  in file "/var/www/html/ParcAuto/vendor/composer/../../src/Command/commandeM
  ailAuto.php". The file was found but the class was not in it, the class nam
  e or namespace probably has a typo.
```

I'm running symfony 4.3.2, the controller i'm trying to call extends AbstractController, my services.yaml is the default one.
I think i missed some configurations but i can't find out which exactly.
Thank you for your help, tell me if you need more information.

Comment: Is the shown code in `commandeMailAuto.php` ?

Comment: Indeed it is, sorry for the delay
the same level as Controller, Entity ...

Comment: Then either rename the file `MailCommand.php` or the class `commandeMailAuto`. Symphony expect the class `foo` to be in the file `foo.php` for autoloading and expect the file `foo.php` to contain the class `foo`

Comment: It seems to have solved my first problem, thank you @Cid.
I now have a problem about the name even though i defined it.

`[WARNING] Some commands could not be registered:`
  `The command defined in "App\Command\mailCommand" cannot have an empty name.`
`There are no commands defined in the "app" namespace.`
  `Did you mean this?  doctrine:mapping`

Comment: Ah, adding the line:
`$this->setName($defaultName)` seems to have solved the issue, my next step is to be able to call the function inside my controller.
I have a MailController.php which defines a  warningMailAction, my goal is to call that action with the command.